# Is there a standard C header file which assigns a numeric value to all of the primitive types?

Tags: c, primitive-types

I have some code which performs differently depending on the underlying data type.  EG:

```
void *some_data = obtain_data();
int data_type = obtain_data_type();
switch(data_type)
{
   case CHAR:
      handle_char(some_data);
      break;
   case SHORT:
      handle_short(some_data);
      break;
   case INT:
      handle_int(some_data);
      break;
   // etc...
}
```

In order for this to work I need an enum or constant which assigns a numeric value to CHAR, SHORT, INT, etc.  EG:

```
enum POD_TYPES
{
   CHAR = 1,
   SHORT = 2,
   INT = 3
   // etc.
}
```

"Rolling my own" is trivial here, but it seems like there ought to be a more established way of accomplishing this.  Is there a standard (or at least commonly available) header file which I can include that already has these values defined somewhere?  I'm not seeing anything listed in the library headers at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/header).  inttypes.h seems to come close, but upon further examination those types are all macros used for casting or determining system-specific min/max values for integers.

Comment: Succinctly — No, not in standard C.

Comment: I'm assuming I'm being downvoted here because the question is very basic?  I'd even agree!  Nevertheless, I was curious, and now we know.  You can all put on your wizard hats and grumble back to the tops of your towers now.  ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no such standard constants, no. There's a lot of things in C that you'd think would be standardized, but aren't.

---

As a side note, you could take the first steps towards a bit more modern C programming by using the C11 `_Generic` keyword and implementing polymorphism behavior instead of using run-time checking of such enums. In fact, you can get rid of the enum entirely:

```
// variant.h / variant.c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void print_func_t (const void* data);

typedef struct
{
  void* data;
  print_func_t* print;
} variant_t;


void print_char  (const void* data) { printf("%c",  *(const char*)  data); }
void print_short (const void* data) { printf("%hd", *(const short*) data); }
void print_int   (const void* data) { printf("%d",  *(const int*)   data); }

void print (const variant_t* var)
{
  var->print(var->data);
}

#define variant_init(var) { \
  .data = &var, \
  .print = _Generic((var), char: print_char, short: print_short, int: print_int) \
}
```

Caller:

```
int main() 
{
  char c = 'A';
  short s = 3;
  int i = 5;

  variant_t var[3] =
  {
    variant_init(c),
    variant_init(s),
    variant_init(i)
  };

  for(size_t i=0; i<3; i++)
  {
    print(&var[i]);
    printf(" ");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It turns out that utilizing function pointers instead of a switch was a much cleaner solution in my case.  Thank you for the inspiration!

Comment: @Groo A switch with cases that are adjacent numbers most often get internally optimized to an array of function pointers. In either case, that part is hidden behind an abstraction layer. any form of polymorphism does end up as some manner of function pointer table. I'm not following how this would turn the code less maintainable though, nor do I understand where you get `something[2]` from. Also, overall this solution should lead to less branches which improves performance, even with the function call overhead in mind.

Comment: @Lundin: never mind, I didn't read the answer well enough the first time.

Answer (score 0):

This is called in C++ a variant type. There are many libraries that do this for you, such as:

1. [QVariant](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.8/qvariant.html) from Qt
2. [Boost any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/any.html)

But remember that there's a price to pay when using such a library. Things are not most efficient when you use variants, but some times it's necessary, such as when you use OPC/UA protocols.

Comment: Ironically, the project I'm working on used to be a full-fledged Qt application in C++.  I started over from scratch in C after I found myself too entrenched in the Qt/C++ features and running into their constraints.  That may have been an overreaction.

Comment: @AlexJohnson I use Qt primarily for their GUIs. Other than that, I depend on boost and others. So, for your case, you can use Boost::any. It has a very peaceful license, too ;) (unlike Qt). Actually if you google "variant type for C" you'll find many other libraries.

Comment: relevant:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734808/variant-datatype-library-for-c

Comment: These aren't an option in C though.