# Handling dynamic function arguments in C

Tags: c, arm, embedded

While coding this project I got in a situation where I have a function that needs to be able to handle both uint8_t, uint16_t and uint32_t variables.

I try to find a decent solution for this to keep this dynamic without making to much mess or tons of duplicate code, but most important, having a save solution.

In the current code I use a struct with an union as argument for a function:

```
typedef struct
{
  DataType type;
  union
  {
    uint8_t uint8;
    uint16_t uint16;
    uint32_t uint32;
  } unsignedInt;
} anySizeUnsignedType;
```

This is an attempt to make the function a bit more dynamic, now however, I have 2 of these types in my function, and need to compare them depending on a third variable.

So, this is basically what I'm trying to do:

```
anySizeUnsignedType Var1 = arg1;
anySizeUnsignedType Var2 = arg2;
uint8_t comparison = arg3;

switch (comparison)
{

    case ABOVE:

      if (Var1 > Var2 )
      {
        retValue = TRUE;
      }    
      break;

    case EQUAL:

      if (Var1 > (Var2 - AnotherVar)
          && (Var1  < (Var2 + AnotherVar)))

      {
        retValue = TRUE;
      }    
      break;

    case BELOW:
      if (Var1 < Var2 )
      {
        retValue = TRUE;
      }    
      break;

    default:
      /* Should be impossible */
      break;

  }
```

The problem: I can't compare "Var" because its an struct of course, I need to compare the uint8_t, uint16_t or uint32_t instead, but is there any way to do this **Save** without having the same code 3 times for all 3 unsigned types?

Or is there a better solution to do this in general? Or maybe a reason to just not wanting to do this?

The reason I'm trying this: handling sensor data from different sensors with different output and keeping their own official resolution,

Comment: You should just remove the union and always store into the uint32_t.

Comment: We had a similar question yesterday, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42245994/584518). You could probably benefit from using the very same kind of polymorph design.

Comment: "above" and "below"?  I can hear my high school math teacher now, "Is one of the variables on a ladder or something?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd be inclined to use

`int compare(uint32_t arg1, uint32_t arg2, uint8_t comparison)`

as the (single) function, and rely on type widening for the narrower versions of `arg1` and `arg2`.