# c - void pointer array with random print

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, printing

I've tried many different ways and seen many different articles to do this but I can't get it to work. I've tried the malloc method. I'm trying to allocate various datatypes into an array of void pointers and print a randomly chosen value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LENGTH 4
void main()
{
    int a = 3;
    float b = 2.5;
    char c = 'H';
    int d = 421;
    char e = 'a';
    void *array;
    array[LENGTH];
    array[0] = &a;
    array[1] = &b;
    array[2] = &c;
    array[3] = &d;
    array[4] = &e;
    printf("%p \n", array[rand() % LENGTH]);
}
```

Comment: If you are using GCC, add `-pedantic-errors` to your command line.

Comment: You need array of pointers `void *array[LENGTH ];` and `#define LENGTH 4` should be `#define LENGTH 5`

Comment: [challenge accepted](https://ideone.com/HPHe1T)

Comment: `array` has not been allocated here. You have just defined it as a pointer on the stack, it will be pointing to anywhere (as stack variables aren't automatically initialised unless you specify it). The line `array[LENGTH];` doesn't do anything at all. The following lines now just write to wherever the array point is pointing. The final line looks correct, however you'll probably have corrupted some memory or caused a memory write violation before this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to print generic *data* of any type, you will need to store the type information along with the data. This is typically done in C by creating an enum. For example:

```
typedef enum
{
  TYPE_INT,
  TYPE_FLOAT,
  TYPE_CHAR,
  TYPE_STR,
} type_t;
```

You can then store this together with the data:

```
typedef struct
{
  type_t type;
  void*  data;
} generic_t;
```

And so the array will have to be an array of structs instead:

```
generic_t array [LENGTH] = { ... };
```

---

Full example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum
{
  TYPE_INT,
  TYPE_FLOAT,
  TYPE_CHAR,
  TYPE_STR,
} type_t;

typedef struct
{
  type_t type;
  void*  data;
} generic_t;


void print_int   (int   x) { printf("%d", x); }
void print_float (float x) { printf("%f", x); }
void print_char  (char  x) { printf("%c", x); }
void print_str   (const char* x) { printf("%s", x); }

void print (const generic_t* gen)
{
  switch(gen->type)
  {
    case TYPE_INT:   print_int(*(int*)gen->data);       break;
    case TYPE_FLOAT: print_float(*(float*)gen->data);   break;
    case TYPE_CHAR:  print_char(*(char*)gen->data);     break;
    case TYPE_STR:   print_str((const char*)gen->data); break;
  }
}

#define LENGTH 5

int main (void)
{
  srand(time(NULL));

  int a = 3;
  float b = 2.5;
  char c = 'H';
  int d = 421;
  char e[] = "hello";

  generic_t array [LENGTH] =
  {
    { TYPE_INT,   &a },
    { TYPE_FLOAT, &b },
    { TYPE_CHAR,  &c },
    { TYPE_INT,   &d },
    { TYPE_STR,   &e },
  };

  for(size_t i=0; i<10; i++) // print 10 random indices of the array
  {
    print( &array[rand()%LENGTH] );
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

This can be made prettier and safer with the use of C11 `_Generic` etc, but the above is the "old school", backwards-compatible way of generic C programming.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you mean `_Generic` can be applied to `print` itself?

Comment: @StoryTeller Only if the parameter passed is a raw `int`, `float` etc and not a struct as in this example. To rewrite this using `_Generic`, the function above would be dropped in favour of a macro.

Comment: I figured as much. Though that presents another problem in the shape of `'H'` and company being integers. So `print(1); print(2.5);` work fine, but `print('H');` would be unexpected. Though that's of course no fault of your solution, just a language defect.

Comment: @StoryTeller Indeed. So it has to be `print( (char)'H' );`.

Comment: @StoryTeller Here's one way to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42245994/584518

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to print the addresses of the variables randomly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LENGTH 5 //There are five variables
void main()
{
    int a = 3;
    float b = 2.5;
    char c = 'H';
    int d = 421;
    char e = 'a';
    void *array[LENGTH] = {&a, &b, &c, &d, &e};
    printf("%p \n", array[rand() % LENGTH]);
}
```

To print the values at these addresses, you will have to make some changes to the program.
- Declare an `Enum` to for the type of data
- Use a anonymous `union` inside a `structure` to hold the data and its type
- A print function to print based on the appropriate type

The program will look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LENGTH 5

enum Type {CHAR = 0, INT, DOUBLE};

struct Variant {
    int type;
    union { 
        char c;   
        int i;    
        double d; 
    };
};

void Print(struct Variant v) {
    switch (v.type) {
        default: 
            printf("None"); 
            break;
        case CHAR: 
            printf(" %c", v.c); 
            break;
        case INT: 
            printf(" %d", v.i); 
            break;
        case DOUBLE: 
            printf(" %f", v.d); 
            break;
    }   
}

int main(void) {
    int a = 3;
    float b = 2.5;
    char c = 'H';
    int d = 421;
    char e = 'a';
    struct Variant array[5] = {0};
    array[0].type = INT; 
    array[0].i = a;

    array[1].type = DOUBLE; 
    array[1].d = b;

    array[2].type = CHAR; 
    array[2].c = c;

    array[3].type = INT; 
    array[3].i = d;

    array[4].type = CHAR; 
    array[4].c = e;

    Print(array[rand() % LENGTH]);  
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: I've made the edits and allocation is not a problem, but it's printing as "0x7ffe322b436c"

Comment: @Redsam121:  You want to print the values at the addresses?

Comment: @Redsam121: Updated the answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish the types before calling printf. Here it is an approach. This approach allows you to use printf as normal: `printf("Random entry: %s\n", FMT_TYPE(array[rand() % LENGTH]))`

Remember to adjust MAX_FORMATTED_LEN.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LENGTH 5

enum Types {
    CHAR,
    INT,
    FLOAT
};

typedef struct {
    void *data;
    int type;
} Type;

#define FMT_CHAR "%c"
#define FMT_INT "%d"
#define FMT_FLOAT "%f"

#define MAX_FORMATTED_LEN 100 // TODO: adjust this: put the maximum length of a printed float or int

char *fmt_type(char *buffer, Type *t);

#define FMT_TYPE(t) fmt_type((char [MAX_FORMATTED_LEN+1]){""}, t)


char *fmt_type(char *buffer, Type *t) {
    switch(t->type) {
        case CHAR:
            sprintf(buffer, FMT_CHAR, *((char *)t->data));
            break;
        case INT:
            sprintf(buffer, FMT_INT, *((int *)t->data));
            break;
        case FLOAT:
            sprintf(buffer, FMT_FLOAT, *((float *)t->data));
            break;
        default:
            printf("Wrong type: %d. Panicking.", t->type);
            exit(-1);
    }
    return buffer;
}



int main()
{
    int i0 = 3, i1 = 421;
    float f0 = 2.5;
    char c0 = 'H', c1 = 'a';

    Type a = { &i0, INT };

    Type b = { &f0, FLOAT };

    Type c = { &c0, CHAR };

    Type d = { &i1, INT };

    Type e = { &c1, CHAR };

    Type *array[LENGTH] = { &a, &b, &c, &d, &e }; 

    //printf("Random entry: %s\n", FMT_TYPE(array[rand() % LENGTH]));

    // the following is just for testing:
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
        printf("entry: %s\n", FMT_TYPE(array[i]));
    }
}
```