# How do I pass type-generic function pointers?

Tags: c

This is my code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <tgmath.h>

 double complex execmathfunc(double complex val, double complex (*mathfunc)(double complex))
 {
     return mathfunc(val);
 }

 int main()
 {
     double complex val = -1;
     val = execmathfunc(val, sqrt); //if I put csqrt here it works
     printf("%.1f+%.1fi", creal(val), cimag(val));
     return 0;
 }
```

This code works if I use `csqrt`, and will output `0.0+1.0i` as expected, but if I use regular `sqrt` (putting my hopes in the type-generic functions of `tgmath.h`), it outputs a garbage value for the real part and 0 for the imaginary part. Is there any way to get around that or do I need to stick with `csqrt` and all the other complex functions when passing them as arguments?

I believe the code behaves this way because the tgmath functions are implemented as functional macros and those only expand if the name is followed by `()`.

Comment: In general, a function pointer must have the exact same type as the function it points to. Otherwise, the parameters and results are looked for/put into the wrong places.

Comment: Yes, but tgmath should choose the correct function by its arguments, just like C++ overloading, shouldn't it?

Comment: @DarkAtom tgmath uses `_Generic` macros. You can't point to a macro.

Comment: Interesting coding goal, yet not possible. Alternatives exist if the hight level goal was known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as type-generic function pointers in C.

However, you could have a struct of pointers for different relevant types, e.g.

```
typedef enum  { 
    USE_FLOAT = 0,
    USE_DOUBLE = 1, 
    // USE_LONG_DOUBLE = 2   // maybe you have this one as well
} complex_component_type_selector;

typedef struct {
    union {
        float complex (*float_)(float complex);
        double complex(*double_)(double complex);
    } function_ptr;
    complex_component_type_selector component_type;
} variant_function;

typedef union {
   union {
       float complex float_;
       double complex double_
   } datum;
   complex_component_type_selector component_type;
} variant_complex_datum;
```

and with that you can pass `variant_complex_function` along with a `variant_complex_datum` to sort-of-kind-of get what you wanted.

... Now, my suggestion is a bit crass and half-assed implementation of some [variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_type). I'm sure there are libraries for C which are more sophisticated and comprehensive... oh yeah, here you go:

[Variant datatype library for C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734808/variant-datatype-library-for-c)

Answer (score 0):

A `_Complex double` is not a `double`, and `sqrt` takes a double, while `csqrt` takes a _Complex double. 
I have not checked implementations, but I would say you are passing what is in fact a pointer to the sqrt function instead of a number.

Comment: I know, but I am `#include`ing `tgmath.h`, which should make the compiler choose the correct function from the type used, just like in C++ overloading.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Actually, that's what tgmath does. If I were to directly call sqrt from main with a _Complex argument, it would work.

Comment: @DarkAtom: Exactly. But the use of a function pointer to redirect that call does not work, because the C compiler does not do type resolution that way.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield, yes, and I am asking if there is a workaround. I am not sure if it is possible to overload execmathfunc itself using the _Generic keyword, because of the complexity of function pointer types.

Comment: @DarkAtom: Not without a lot of tedious boilerplate, I don't think. And it would be rather brittle, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

> I believe the code behaves this way because the tgmath functions are implemented as functional macros and those only expand if the name is followed by ().

Yes

> Is there any way to get around that ... ?

No direct way around it.

Using `<tgmath.h>`, code cannot extract the function that would be called with an object of some type.

You could write your own function set using `_Generic`, yet I think you know that and are trying to avoid it.